# Can I configure Visual Studio 2010 to show warnings only in my source code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, suppress-warnings

I like having a high level of warnings (usually W4). However, with a warning level of 4 or higher, I get a lot of warnings from Windows headers and from third party headers, which makes it very difficult to find the ones I can actually do something about.

Hence my question: Can I tell Visual Studio to show warnings only for those files which belong to my current project?

Answer (score 0):

This would be especially useful when running code analysis. Why show all those warnings for code that I don't own?

I found one thing that might help:

Right click anywhere on one of the rows in the Error List and click Grouping->Path. The path to the file will show up on the left. Now you can collapse all the paths to code that you want to ignore.

It's not ideal, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: This sounds quite helpful. Are you sure you have VS2010? I do not have the Path available and I see only Sorting but not Grouping.

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm using VS2017 so I don't know if this is in VS2010.